# Finding the positive projection in the frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I am trying to find the positive projection in the frobenius norm of a real matrix. Consider the following matrix $\hat{Z}$:
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&5&0\\0&8&9\end{bmatrix}

I need to find Z such that $\lvert\lvert Z-\hat{Z} \rvert\rvert_{F}^{2}$ is minimum. Here F indicates the frobenius norm.

According to the paper [Computing a Nearest Symmetric Positive Semidefinite Matrix by Nicholas J Higam](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379588902236), it possible to find the frobenius norm positive approximant $Z$ by theorem 2.1: 
Take $B = (\hat{Z} + \hat{Z^{T}})/2$ 
Let $B = UH$ be a polar decomposition 
Then $Z = (B+H)/2$ is the positive approximant.

Then, in equations 2.1 and 2.2, the paper proposes a faster method to find the positive approximant using eigendecomposition. According to this method, let $Q$ be the (right) eigenvector matrix of $\hat{Z}$ and $v = [v_{1}, v_{2}, ... v_{m}]$ the vector of eigenvalues.
Then, the eigenvalue decomposition of $\hat{Z} = Q \times diag\{v\} \times Q^{*}$
Then positive approximant $Z = Q \times diag\{ max(v_{1},0), ... max(v_{m},0)\} \times Q^{*}$

Using the two methods, I am getting different results. The first method gives me the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0 \\
1&5&4 \\
0&4&9\\
\end{bmatrix}
Code for method 1:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as sl

Z = np.matrix([[1,2,0],[0,5,0],[0,8,9]]).astype(np.float32)

b = 0.5*(Z + Z.T)
u,h = sl.polar(b)
pos1 = (b+h)*0.5
```

While the second method gives me
\begin{bmatrix} 
1.2380&0.4761&-0.9523 \\
0.4761&0.9523&-1.9047 \\
-0.9523&-1.9047&12.8095 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Code for method 2:

```
import numpy as np

Z = np.matrix([[1,2,0],[0,5,0],[0,8,9]]).astype(np.float32)
w,v = np.linalg.eig(Z)
wd = np.diag(w)
pos2 = np.matmul(v,np.matmul(wd, v.T))
```

Why am I getting two different results?

Comment: did you calculate the minimal distance for both of these? If the polar decomposition is not unique, for example, then the answer won't be unique.

Comment: besides, your matrix wd is not just diagonal of w, the paper says negative eigenvalues are replaced by $0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found your error. In your second method, you must use spectral decomposition of $B = \dfrac{Z+Z^T}{2}$, not $Z$ itself. Besides, your $Z$ and the paper's $Z$ are different and that's not a good practice. Anyway here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
Z = np.matrix([[1,2,0],[0,5,0],[0,8,9]]).astype(np.float32)
w,v = np.linalg.eig(0.5*(Z + Z.T))
wd = np.diag(w)

for i in range(3):
    if wd[i,i]<0:
        wd[i,i]==0
pos2 = np.matmul(v,np.matmul(wd, v.T))
```

Comment: The actual paper I was using had referenced Higam's paper, and Z was used differently in both, hence my confusion. Anyway thanks for clearing this up, I'm getting identical results now.

Comment: Also if you are familiar with the paper, can you please direct me to some references that can help me understand the proof of theorem 2.1?

Comment: that proof does not seem to use anything advanced, so I don't think I can find a resource explaining those steps only. If you got the time, take a proof based linear algebra class or numerical linear algebra class. I used Trefethen and Bau's numerical linear algebra it might be of some help.